# How to get row of photos on across top of Facebook page

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-pages

Other Facebook pages have a row of little pictures across the top. How can I make that happen on [my page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/3H-Craftworks-Creations-by-Artisans-with-Disabilities/12696679246)?

Answer (score 2):

The example page in the question is a **page** as opposed to a **profile**. So, strictly speaking, it is the **page layout upgrade** that is required to show the pictures, rather than the earlier **profile layout upgrade**. The **page layout upgrade** is scheduled to occur for all pages on 10 March 2011, according to Facebook.

Comment: You may have a link on your page to upgrade.  One appeared on mine about a week ago; once you upgrade, you can't go back.

Comment: @TomG – I’ve seen an email from Facebook that describes an option to voluntarily choose the page layout upgrade, earlier than 10 March. So far, I haven’t personally seen one of those options. The same email also says that all pages (remaining) will be involuntarily upgraded *on* 10 March. That is slightly different to the profile layout upgrade that started its involuntarily upgrade on a particular date, and extended over a period of days. So it looks as though 10 March is the longest anyone will have to wait to see a page layout upgrade.

Comment: We have reached the page layout upgrade date of 10 March now. So Sheila’s page should have been automatically upgraded to allow for five pictures across the top of the page. It does of course require some pictures to be uploaded, if the picture positions are currently blank.

Answer (score 0):

It is the new profile feature which Facebook is rolling out. Read more about it on [Facebook's blog](http://www.facebook.com/blog.php?post=462201327130)

Comment: Strictly speaking it is the new page feature (which is very similar to the new profile feature) that is required for the questioner’s page to show pictures.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess I posted that in quite a hurry.